# How to Sorting Column after dot in decimal number - Ms access

Tags: sql, database, sorting, ms-access, filter

I want to sort column Like... 
Example : 
1.1,
1.2,
1.3,
.
.
.
,1.9,
1.10,
1.11,
1.12,
.
.
,2.1,
2.2,
2.3,
.
.
,2.9,
2.10,
2.11,
.
.
,3.1,
3.2,
... So on..

I Tried this,

```
    SELECT SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber
    FROM SectionName
    ORDER BY SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber;
```

[But I get this kind of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHSPQ.png)

Can anyone guide me? how can I filter this column in Ms Access?

Comment: This is going to be hard to do in Access (assuming your column is text).  First, you'll have to logically separate the number before and after the dot, then you'll have to cast those texts to numbers, and sort.  If you have a long term need for this, I recommend creating two separate numeric columns.

Comment: yes, you are right. but any alternate easy way? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I don't know Access well enough to give an answer.  The query would be very complicated.

Comment: Okay ,Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: If you use VBA, you could use the [`Split`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_split.asp) funtion, and the order by two fields

Comment: Have you tried to convert thoss values to numbers and then sort these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by a fancy expression converting the second part to an integer, then order by that:

```
SELECT 
    UnderISMDocNumber
FROM 
    SectionName
ORDER BY 
    Int(Val([UnderISMDocNumber])), Val(Mid(Str(CCur(Val([UnderISMDocNumber]))-Int(Val([UnderISMDocNumber]))),3));
```

But you are in serious trouble, as you mix string sorting and numeric sorting when you use entries like **3.03** with leading zero(es) as you can see:

```
UnderISMDocNumber
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
1.11
1.12
1.13
2
2.1
2.2
3.01
3.10
3.02
3.03
3.04
3.5
3.11
3.12
3.13
```

So, either use zeroes and plain numeric sorting on `Val([UnderISMDocNumber])`, or don't use leading zeroes in the second part. You can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL:

```
SELECT SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber
FROM SectionName
ORDER BY SplitOrderField(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, 0), SplitOrderField(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, 1);
```

And in a VBA Module:

```
Public Function SplitOrderField (str as String, i as Intiger)as Long
    SplitOrderField = CLng(Split (str)(i)) 
End Function
```

Comment: @Gustav has got a point there: if 0.01 <> 0.1 <> 0.10, you must indicate how the right side of the point is valued. Seems my answer is in accurate, and so is the question...

Comment: Thanks For you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

While marlan's solution is fine, you can also use a little more complicated SQL solution to split the string. That has the advantage of being able to be called outside of the Access application, and using ADO and DAO.

```
SELECT SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber
FROM SectionName
ORDER BY 
     IIf(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber LIKE "*.*", Val(Left(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, 
           Val(Left(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, InStr(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, ".") - 1),
            SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber
     )
     , 
     IIf(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber LIKE "*.*", Val(Left(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, 
           Len(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber) - InStr(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber, "."))), 
            0
     )
```

Explanation:

`Val` casts strings to a number
`InStr` locates the dot in the string.
`Left` returns the left part of the string.
`Right` returns the part right of the string.

An alternative, relying on the numeric nature of the column:

```
SELECT SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber
FROM SectionName
ORDER BY Int(Val(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber)),
         Val(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber) -Int(Val(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber)) * (InStr(StrReverse(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber), ".") - 1);
```

Explanation:

`Int(Val(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber))` is the whole-number part of the number.
`Val(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber) -Int(Val(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber))` is the decimal part of the number (number - whole number part)
`*(InStr(StrReverse(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber), ".") - 1)` multiplies the decimal part with the number of decimal places

Comment: Thanks For your valuable feedback. It's helpful

Answer (score 0):

If the part before the number is a fixed length (such as a single digit as in your examples), then there is a simple short-cur:

```
ORDER BY LEN(SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber),
         SectionName.UnderISMDocNumber
```